# Does upstart pass an entire script body to shell for execution or process line-by-line?

Tags: upstart

My upstart job is failing in pre-start, when it moves any previous logfile to a backup:

```
pre-start script
  mv -f $LOGDIR/$LOGFILE $LOGDIR/$LOGFILE.bak
  touch $LOGDIR/$LOGFILE
end script
```

I expect the `mv` to fail if the previous logfile doesn't exist, so added the `touch` to ensure that the last command in the script body returns 0.

However if the script runs when there isn't a previous logfile in the log directory, it fails in pre-start:

```
Jan  9 17:21:14 ip-172-30-1-54 kernel: [  250.154908] init: myscript state changed from starting to security
Jan  9 17:21:14 ip-172-30-1-54 kernel: [  250.154951] init: myscript state changed from security to pre-start
Jan  9 17:21:14 ip-172-30-1-54 kernel: [  250.155652] init: myscript pre-start process (1425)
Jan  9 17:21:14 ip-172-30-1-54 kernel: [  250.157167] init: myscript pre-start process (1425) terminated with status 1
Jan  9 17:21:14 ip-172-30-1-54 kernel: [  250.157280] init: myscript goal changed from start to stop
```

If I then start the script again, it gets through pre-start successfully and into the main script body:

```
Jan  9 17:21:29 ip-172-30-1-54 kernel: [  265.444327] init: myscript state changed from starting to security
Jan  9 17:21:29 ip-172-30-1-54 kernel: [  265.444371] init: myscript state changed from security to pre-start
Jan  9 17:21:29 ip-172-30-1-54 kernel: [  265.445359] init: myscript pre-start process (1431)
Jan  9 17:21:29 ip-172-30-1-54 kernel: [  265.447203] init: myscript pre-start process (1431) exited normally
Jan  9 17:21:29 ip-172-30-1-54 kernel: [  265.447249] init: myscript state changed from pre-start to spawned
Jan  9 17:21:29 ip-172-30-1-54 kernel: [  265.447874] init: myscript main process (1434)
Jan  9 17:21:29 ip-172-30-1-54 kernel: [  265.447896] init: myscript state changed from spawned to post-start
Jan  9 17:21:29 ip-172-30-1-54 kernel: [  265.447972] init: myscript state changed from post-start to running
```

From this behavior, I'm inferring that the script body is executed one line at a time, and any failure terminates the script (much like a `make`). The [documentation](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#script) of the `script` directive does not give any guidance:

> Allows the specification of a multi-line block of shell code to be executed. Block is terminated by end script.

Can anyone either confirm or deny my belief? If confirmed, I can simply run a self-contained shell script with `exec`. If denied, I need to look elsewhere for my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was under the impression that Upstart ran the script as a whole using `/bin/sh`, with exit on error ([`set -e`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19622198/what-does-set-e-in-a-bash-script-mean), or the command line option `-e`). That is, if any command whose exit code is not checked returns a non-zero exit code, terminate the script immediately.

Indeed, given a configuration:

```
description "Testing upstart"
task
script 
set -o > /tmp/blah
end script
```

One finds the following options set:

```
Current option settings
errexit         on
noglob          off
ignoreeof       off
interactive     off
monitor         off
noexec          off
stdin           off
xtrace          off
verbose         off
vi              off
emacs           off
noclobber       off
allexport       off
notify          off
nounset         off
nolog           off
debug           off
```

Though I am mystified as to how it ran the second time, since, for any configuration of the form:

```
pre-start script
false
# any number of commands
end script
```

None of the commands after `false` were executed, as expected, so the `touch` command should never have executed and the `mv` should have failed on subsequent runs as well.

`set -e` is not unusual - you'll find that, for example, package maintenance scripts are also run with it enabled. That is why you would see boilerplate of the form:

```
command that could fail but is not essential || true
```

---

Indeed, [the Cookbook says this too](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#debugging-a-script-which-appears-to-be-behaving-oddly):

> If a `script` section appears to be behaving in an odd fashion, the chances are that one of the commands is failing. Remember that Upstart runs every `script` section using `/bin/sh -e`. This means that if any simple command fails, the shell will exit.

See also: Sections [11.58.1](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#develop-scripts-using-bin-sh) and [18.7](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#check-a-script-section-for-errors).

Comment: Thanks, I missed that section on running with `-e`. Your comment about `touch` being executed made me realize that Ialso  jumped to a conclusion about what was happening: I also have a post-stop script that writes a trailing timestamp in the logfile. I haven't checked, but I'm betting that it runs even if pre-start fails, so the file would be there.

Comment: My ultimate solution was to put a `touch` before the `mv`, to guarantee that something exists. Ugly, but I expect to replace the physical logfiles with a log-roller sometime soon, so the entire pre-start can go away.

Comment: @kdgregory when pre-start fails the service transitions to stop/waiting, so the post-stop section is executed.